# Get data from column in another sheet with a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I've a workbook which has two sheets, "INFO" & "paste".

[image: sheet1]

and

[image: sheet2]

I'm trying to use the sum of the values of the column E ("DPD") i.e. 28 (present in cell E20) & the other data in same column one after the other to get a result like below:

[image: result]

I tried the below code but its doing nothing

```
Sub Range_Gen_Method()

Dim targetCell As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

targetCell = Sheets("INFO").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Value

For i = 1 To targetCell
    For j = 1 To Range("E7").Value
        Sheets("paste").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = j & " - " & 28 & " to " & j + 1 & " - " & 28
    Next
    Range("B3").Offset(1, 0).Select
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: "it's doing nothing" is not helpful. It's doing something, just not the right thing. Please step through your code line by line and let us know where the errors occur. Also, the Immediate window is of great utility...use it to evaluate large expressions in your code where rolling over with the mouse proves insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of VBA for that. You can do it using a formula and then pasting values:

[image]

Yes, **first cell is empty (can do it manually)**, but rest of results can be obtained with an formula. My formula in `C3` is:

```
=SUM($A$2:A2)+1&"/"&SUM($A$2:$A$14)&" - "&SUM($A$2:A3)&"/"&SUM($A$2:$A$14)
```

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

**EDIT:** The trick here is using dinaminc ranges. Notices that first  and third sum (I mean `SUM($A$2:A2)` and `SUM($A$2:A3)`) are summing up a range with only an absolute reference, so the range changes in each row

Comment: BTW, the reason I was looking for a VBA solution is that I want to do this on multiple files at once and writing one cells value manually for a lot of files is time consuming and not the best way to go about